# Table getting reduced after adding Display: block

Tags: html, css, html-table

I had a table that took the entire surrounding div. In order to make it responsive, I wanted to add a horizontal scroll bar. I added the attributes

```
display: block; 
overflow-x: auto;
```

to the table, but it reduced the size of the table. I figured out that it was the display: block; attribute that did that. I tried adding width:100% but it didn't work. Would someone have an idea on how to fix this?

An image of before adding the display block attribute:
https://ibb.co/kLCETv

and after:
https://ibb.co/dptXFa

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please wrap the table with a div and give the styles to that div instead of table.

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you table into `div`, changing `table` into `block` will obviously change its behavior

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=6>
    <tr>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
      <th>Placeholder</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
      <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```